# Tcl script started from jenkins turns the command to lowercase

Tags: docker, jenkins, tcl

I'm having a strange issue when running a tcl command in jenkins.

The tcl script has the following lines (**pay attention to the uppercase I in Id**):

```
foreach name $docker_names {
  set name "TestName"
  puts $name
  set command "docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}' ${name} > /home/temp/id.txt"
  send -- "$command\n"
  expect "$"
}
```

In the jeknins log I see that the job fails because what is sent **in the second iteration of the loop** is the command above but in lowercase. I need the **I in Id** to be uppercase.

This is what is sent in **the second iteration of the loop**:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.id}}' testname > /home/temp/id.txt
```

**NOTE:** In the first iteration, everything is sent correctly.

Anyone has an idea of why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Tcl doesn't change the case of strings unless explicitly asked to do so. Have you tried getting the string to be sent to be explicitly echoed back to you before you `send` it?

Comment: If you're refering to something like: puts "docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}' ${name} > /home/temp/id.txt", yes, it returns ok. This only happens when I'm running the script from jenkins.

Comment: It sounds like there's something else going on as well that is applying a transform to some of the program text that you're not expecting. Alas, that's *very* easily done when you've got a complex stack of software. As a general thing, I find it easiest to try to keep each language's scripts in its own file so that there's no extra layers of gotchas to make your day horrible, but that's not helpful to you.

Comment: I start to think that maybe it's related with the way I'm saving the output of the send command to a file using the ">". I will try to find other way to set a variable to the output of the send command.

Comment: Try to check putting quotes around ${name} or invoke the command indirectly from a batch file using set command `mydockerscript.bat '${name}'` and use content of batch file as `docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}' 
"%1" > /home/temp/id.txt"`

Comment: Hi SACn. Putting quotes around does not solve. I don't understand how to do your second sugestion. I'm using a centOS machine. Should I use a shell script file? Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Does it changes other variable/value to upper case too? Jenkins does not do anything special here. You can try out adding some more debug puts with upper case variable to validate that

Comment: It changes to lowercase, not uppercase. The change is only in the contents of the command variable, not any other (that I know). And it only happens after the first iteration of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

It can't happen from pure TCL perspective. It's a side effect of TCL interpreter integration in Jenkins: I guess there's a hidden layer that parses the script and modify it according to non-TCL syntax.
I would do 2 trials:
First is to minimize the TCL parsings f the string:

```
foreach name $docker_names {
  set name "TestName"
  puts $name
  set command [concat {docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}'} $name { > /home/temp/id.txt} "\n"]
  send -- $command
  expect "$"
}
```

If it doesn't help, try backquoting the curlybraces that may be interpreted by another layer:

```
foreach name $docker_names {
  set name "TestName"
  puts $name
  set command "docker inspect --format='\{\{.Id\}\}' ${name} > /home/temp/id.txt"
  send -- "$command\n"
  expect "$"
}
```